# PHP 7 reserved words: resource, object, mixed and numeric

Tags: php, reserved-words

[PHP RFC: Reserve Even More Types in PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reserve_even_more_types_in_php_7) claims the following words are now reserved in the context of class, interface and trait names and namespaces: [resource, object, mixed and numeric](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reserve_even_more_types_in_php_7#result).

However, the following code is [valid](https://3v4l.org/JC7NU) in PHP 7.

```
class resource {}
class object {}
class mixed {}
class numeric {}
```

I want to call my interface `Resource` but I would be loathe if PHP suddenly made it a reserved word mid-PHP 7 release stream.

- In light of this apparent conflict of an accepted PR with the empirical evidence submitted herein and the [absence of any such reservations in the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f4d1af7981a4173b25e9ef84fcc550b8b0df72c0/Zend/zend_compile.c#L151-L165), should I be safe to call my interface `Resource`, or not?
- Can a patch for this PR still be implemented in PHP 7.x or must it now wait until PHP-next?
- Is the absence of any commitment to implement it an indicator that it may never be implemented in any future version?

---

EDIT: In light of the discussion that followed highlighting these words have only been [*soft reserved*](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php) it seems there is one additional key question to be asked. It seems to me a word should either be reserved or not and that a *soft reservation* state makes no sense, therefore:

- Why was the soft reservation state created instead of "hard" reserving these words?

Comment: Just call it `ResourceInterface` and save yourself the hassle

Comment: @naththedeveloper I do not suffix `Interface` to my interface names and more than anyone else suffixes `Class` to their class names.

Comment: The only reason I suggested it is that it's the [PHP-FIG](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/bylaws/002-psr-naming-conventions.md) standard.

Comment: @naththedeveloper that is the most idiotic decision in that entire psr imo... The `Interface` suffix adds nothing of value.

Comment: Name your interface as accurate as possible.

Comment: @naththedeveloper some decision are pretty stupid (e.g. placing `{` in some cases on same line and in some on newline).

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but in this very case it solves the problem, like it or not.

Comment: Appending `Foo` also solves the problem and has the same usefulness.

Comment: @PeeHaa some community we have here, can't even make a suggestion without having people take out there personal problems with PSR standards on me like I'm the person to blame for some of their decisions..

Comment: @naththedeveloper If I had said I wanted to name a class you wouldn't have even begun this discussion, so specifying an interface is a decision I now regret, because it has derailed this discussion. Please do not allow yourself to miss the point. `Resource` is the best name for my class and I want to use it if at all possible. The purpose of this question is to discover if it is, in fact, possible both now and in the future.

Comment: There is no way to tell you if it is possible in the future. We can't see into the future. I'd suggest you to not use potential reserved names.

Comment: @naththedeveloper this is a technical Q&A. Nobody attacked you personally. I only judged based on the technical solution provided. So yes you can make a suggestion and yes I am allowed to say it's not useful.

Comment: On a related note: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/php-fig/Potawlu2CrQ

Answer (score 3):

> but I would be loathe if PHP suddenly made it a reserved word mid-PHP 7 release stream.

Well with the knowledge you have it would be stupid to name it e.g. Resource and take your chances.

> In light of this apparent conflict of an accepted PR with the empirical evidence submitted herein and the absence of any such reservations in the source, should I be safe to call my interface Resource, or not?

No. Unless you know for sure it is of the table again it would be pretty stupid.

> Can a patch for this PR still be implemented in PHP 7.x or must it now wait until PHP-next?

They are currently soft reserved as per [our manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php):

```
Soft reserved words
resource (as of PHP 7)  object (as of PHP 7)    mixed (as of PHP 7) numeric (as of PHP 7)
```

whether they will actually be hard reserved shouldn't matter.

> Is the absence of any commitment to implement it an indicator that it may never be implemented in any future version?

Nobody has a crystal ball no. Nobody can tell you what happens in any an all future version.

> Why was the soft reservation state created instead of "hard" reserving these words?

Because it's possibly a pretty big BC break. The same has happened when deprecating the old `mysql_*` API. This way everybody knows way in advance to not use it before it becomes a problem.

Comment: I'm not looking for a crystal ball, I'm looking for someone with knowledge of the relevant internals discussions who can clarify what "soft-reserved" actually means for the future of the language since the manual doesn't go into any details whatsoever.

Comment: You are saying that "The following list of words have had soft reservations placed on them. Whilst **they may still be used** as class, interface, and trait names (as well as in namespaces), **usage of them is highly discouraged since they may be used in future versions** of PHP." is not clear?

Comment: That is fairly clear. I was looking under the *soft reserved words* heading and didn't see any text. It is a strange layout to me that the soft reservation discussion appears under the *reserved words* heading. It still speaks nothing to the road map for soft reserved words. If I knew I could use the name until PHP 8 I may accept that risk whereas if it may be clobbered as early as PHP 7.2 I might not.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions Even though there were someone who is in php internals here, he absolutely can't say when something gets hard reserved. It could be in any version between 7.1 and 8 or even later. Between 7.1 and 8 will be a few years and php internals might decide in one moment to hard reserve them. Instead of trying to get answer to an impossible accurately answerable question, you should just not use any potential reserved words. I'm not sure what's so hard about that. I'm pretty sure `resource` is *not* the most accurate name.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *it is* and I fail to see how you could ever positively assert any different given that you have not even had the briefest of introductions to my domain.

Comment: @PeeHaa I cannot accept the answer that soft reservation was created to avoid BC breaks because: (1) it was an equally big BC break to reserve all the scalar words that *were* reserved in PHP 7 and (2) the major version increment not only permits such BC breaks but is the ideal opportunity to introduce them. The point being, the soft/hard dichotomy was created during the introduction of PHP 7 so it cannot be anything to do with backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of "soft reservation" is to give you time to fix your code. This allows you to upgrade to PHP 7 now, rather than making you first find all uses of these keywords and fix them. But you're being warned that you should fix them, since future updates may break your code.

It's similar to the reason for deprecating features that are planned to be removed in the future.

Regarding why they chose to hard-reserve some words while soft-reserving others, it's probably because they knew that there were many sites using the latter, so reserving them immediately would make upgrading harder for many sites.